# using CASE with ISNULL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a select statement which is followed by a union. Inside the select, there is a where clause. I am trying to add in the following code to the where clause but I'm having an issue getting it to work out:

```
declare @BudgetFilter int;
set @Budgetfilter = 0;

AND CASE @BudgetFilter WHEN 0 THEN ISNULL(Project.Contribution, 0) >= 25000 END
```

The error is with the >. Error message: "Incorrect syntax near '>'."

Some additional background. Budget filter may be one of 3 values. 0,1,2 which translate into >=25K, <25K, <0 respectively.
There are other filters(dropdown value selections) that i am working once I get past this issue.

Thanks.
A

Comment: The `THEN` part of the `CASE` statement is a `SET` operation, so you cannot use an operator in it.  Can you provide a little more info as to what you are expecting to see as a result?

Comment: It should probably look more like this: `AND ((@BudgetFilter = 0 AND ISNULL(Project.Contribution, 0) >= 25000) OR (@BudgetFilter = 1 AND ISNULL(Project.Contribution, 0) < 25000) AND...`

Answer (score 6):

`CASE` is an expression that returns a single value. You are attempting to use it as control of flow logic to optionally include a filter, and it doesn't work that way. Maybe something like this would work:

```
AND COALESCE(Project.Contribution, 0) >= CASE @BudgetFilter 
  WHEN 0 THEN 25000 ELSE 2000000000 END
-- guessing that 2 billion is enough to always be greater
-- than the highest valid contribution
```

Expanding to your three conditions, you need to use multiple expressions because you can't use `CASE`, again, to change `>=` to `<`. So something like:

```
AND COALESCE(Project.Contribution, 0) >= CASE @BudgetFilter
  WHEN 0 THEN 25000 ELSE 2000000000 END
AND COALESCE(Project.Contribution, 0) < CASE
  @BudgetFilter WHEN 1 THEN 25000 WHEN 2 THEN 0 ELSE -2000000000 END)
```

Or you can use the OR conditionals as mentioned in the comments:

```
AND ((@BudgetFilter = 0 AND Project.Contribution >= 25000)
  OR (@BudgetFilter IN (1,2) AND Project.Contribution < CASE
    @BudgetFilter WHEN 1 THEN 25000 ELSE 0 END))
```

Or you can just use dynamic SQL, which may be useful if you have a lot of other criteria and/or you are having difficulty getting consistent behavior from the plans for the above variations:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT ...
   WHERE ...
   AND COALESCE(Project.Contribution, 0) '
+ CASE @BudgetFilter
  WHEN 0 THEN ' >= 25000'
  WHEN 1 THEN ' < 25000'
  WHEN 2 THEN ' < 0' END + ';';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

(And [in case you're wondering why I use `COALESCE` instead of `ISNULL`](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/). That said, the `COALESCE`/`ISNULL` is really meaningless here, because the `COALESCE`d value (`0`) will only potentially meet the `< 25000` criteria - and I'm not sure that's what you intended at all.)

Comment: Thank you all for all the answers. You've set me on the right path :). I settled on using the following approach:
AND ((@BudgetFilter = 0 AND ISNULL(Project.Contribution, 0) >= 25000) OR 
                (@BudgetFilter = 1 AND ISNULL(Project.Contribution, 0) < 25000)  OR
             (@BudgetFilter = 2 AND ISNULL(Project.Contribution, 0) > 0))